# Add new tag to welcome email in WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

WordPress Multisite sends a welcome email with specific available tags, is there way to add more tags to it, I did not found anywhere about it, `CUSTOMTAG1` or `CUSTOMTAG2` is page content fetched from specific page id:

> Dear User,
>
> Your new account is set up.
>
> You can log in with the following information:
>   Username: USERNAME
>   Password: PASSWORD
>
> LOGINLINK
>
> CUSTOMTAG1
>
> CUSTOMTAG2
>
> Thanks!
>
> --The Team @ SITE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Try using wp get_user_meta function to grab the custom user field from the db and populate in welcome email. see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the automatic email and send your own using the filter [**`wpmu_welcome_user_notification`**](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L1557). You have to pull the email from the user ID, the `$meta` parameter comes empty:

```
// return false stops the automatic email
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_user_notification', function( $userid, $password, $meta ) {
    # Your own wp_mail
    // wp_mail( $user_email, wp_specialchars_decode( $subject ), $message, $message_headers );
    return false;
}, 10, 3 );
```